# In a react component class where exactly is the "props" object being pulled from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

To get straight to the point, in a react class based component where does the `prop` object come from?

I am following the official React tic-tac-toe game tutorial.

Firstly, when I take a look at the code for the react `Component` class (which we extend when creating a React component) I observe that the function has 3 parameters `Component(props, context, updater)` but I am puzzled as to why in the cases where super() is called only `props` is passed like so `super(props)`. 
Shouldn't there be values passed for `context` and `updater` also? Why is it that there are no errors when the code is run without `super` being called?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Square extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <span>
                <button className="square" onClick={ () => { alert("click") } }>
                    {this.props.value}
                </button>
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

To be clear, I understand that the `value` property in `{this.props.value}` comes from the property passed to `Square` `<Square value={index}/>;` which is a child in another component (`Board` in the case of the React tutorial) but this is not what I'am referring to.

Comment: https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/ this will give you a very good idea about why super(props)

Answer (score 0):

Props are the properties that are passed from the Super class to the class you create using `extends Components` in React.

Similar to what happens in OOPS where the parent class properties are passed to the children in the constructor . similar way the props are passed in React this applies in case of functional components too

> Note - Please do not confuse it with OOPS concepts [ just to give a
>   Oversimplified version]

Comment: But then wouldn't it be appropriate to call `super()` before the code can run without errors? Why does it run without `super` being called?

Comment: that is the reason i mentioned it is an oversimplification of the concept. this is handled by react internally when ever we extend the class it inherits all the stuff from the parent and props being a part of the same

Answer (score 0):

One thing is necessary: the parent's (which is `Component` class) constructor must be invoked within any React *class component*.

What `super` does (inside `Square`'s `constructor`) is to invoke `Component`'s constructor with `Square`'s `props`. *(Hope it's not complicated)*

1. If `Square` has a `constructor` then you should call `super` implicitly.
2. If `Square` doesn't have a constructor, then `Component`'s constructor will automatically be invoked when using `<Square />`.

Also you don't use `context` or `updater` directly in your components. So there is no need to define them there.